# How can I locate items using xpath from below elements?

Tags: xpath

I've created some xpath expressions to locate the first item by it's "index" after "h4". However, I did something wrong that is why it doesn't work at all. I expect someone to take a look into it and give me a workaround.
I tried with:

```
//div[@id="schoolDetail"][1]/text()  --For the Name
//div[@id="schoolDetail"]//br[0]/text()  --For the PO Box
```

Elements within which items I would like the expression to locate is pasted below:

```
<div id="schoolDetail" style=""><h4>School Detail: <a href="javascript:backToList();">Click here to go back to list</a></h4> GOLD DUST FLYING SERVICE, INC.<br>PO Box 75<br><br>TALLADEGA AL 36260<br> <br>Airport: TALLADEGA MUNICIPAL (ASN)<br>Manager: JEAN WAGNON<br>Phone: 2563620895<br>Email: golddustflyingse@bellsouth.net<br>Web: <br><br><a href="https://www.aopa.org/airports/ASN/business/19978" target="_new">View in AOPA Airports</a> (Opens in new tab) <br><br></div>
```

By the way, the resulting values should be:

1. GOLD DUST FLYING SERVICE, INC.
2. PO Box 75

Comment: what should be the resulting values?

Comment: Thanks sir  RomanPerekhrest, for your response. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to locate required text nodes by appropriate index:

```
//div[@id="schoolDetail"]/text()[1] // For "GOLD DUST FLYING SERVICE, INC."

//div[@id="schoolDetail"]/text()[2] // For "PO Box 75"
```

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your effective solution. Things can never go wrong when you take anything into consideration.

Comment: Sir Andersson, you might wanna follow the link if you have time to spare "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843978/unable-to-fit-the-two-expressions-into-my-script"

Answer (score 1):

Locator to get both elements:

```
//*[@id='schoolDetail']/text()[position()<3]
```

Explanation:

`[x]` - xPath could sort values using predicate in square brackets.

**`x` - could be integer, in this case it will automatically be compared with element's position in this way `[position()=x]`:**

`//div[2]` - searches for 2nd div, similar to `div[position()=2]`

**In case predicate `[x]` is not an integer** - it will be automatically converted to boolean value and will return only elements, where result of x is `true`, for example:

`div[position() <= 4]` - search for first four div elements, as `4 <= 4,` but on the 5th and above element position will be more than 4

> Important: please check following locators on this page: 
>   https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmessages.asp
>
> `//table//tr[1]` - will return every 1st row in each table ! (12 found
>   elements, same as tables on the page)
>
> `(//table//tr)[1]` - will return 1st row in the first found table (1 found element)

Comment: added a lot of explanation =)