# Unable to fit the two expressions into my script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script to scrape documents from a web page using python in combination with selenium. However, the only thing I got stuck is print the value. As selenium doesn't support indexing in text, I can't think further to accomplish this. Taking a look into my code You will get to know what I meant. I've commented out the two lines to be rectified. Thanks in advance. Here is what I've written so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.aopa.org/learntofly/school/')

driver.find_element_by_id('searchTerm').send_keys('All')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('btnSearch').click()
time.sleep(3)
for items in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td/a'):
    driver.execute_script(items.get_attribute('href'))
    time.sleep(3)
    for docs in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="schoolDetail"]'):                              
        print(docs.text)

        # Instead of docs I wanted to print the two expressions but can't

        # Name = docs.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="schoolDetail"]/text()[1]') 
        # Address = docs.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="schoolDetail"]/text()[2]')
        # print(Name, Address)

    for back_links in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="schoolDetail"]//h4/a'):
        driver.execute_script(back_links.get_attribute('href'))

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you share `HTML` code for the same and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code and let me know in case of any issues:

```
Name = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[1].textContent', docs) # To get Name text value
Address = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent', docs) # To get Address text value
```

Comment: No way, sir Andersson!!! It works like magic. A little explanation would be very helpful or any link to understand the "return arguments". Thanks a zillion. You are really the gem of a guy.

Comment: `arguments[0]` in this case is the same as `document.getElementById("schoolDetail")`, but there is no need to define same `WebElement` again as we've already defined `docs`. So we use `'return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent', docs` instead of `'return document.getElementById("schoolDetail").childNodes[3].textContent'`. `return` operator allows you not just to execute `JavaScript`, but also get the values from its output

Comment: Thanks again sir, for the clarity.

Answer (score 0):

your commented expressions are retrieving webelements.  I'm assuming that there is just one name, so the code should use find_element_by_xpath (without the "s").  If you want the text that appears in those elements, ask for that attribute:

```
    Name = docs.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="schoolDetail"]/text()[1]').text
    Address = docs.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="schoolDetail"]/text()[2]').text
```